# Which is the simplest QFT that describes the interaction between electrons and photons?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, action, interactions

I want to understand how electrons and photons interact according to quantum field theory (QFT). I know that there are several QFTs, and it seems unnecessary to start from a QFT that is more complicated than it needs to be.

**So, what is the simplest QFT, i.e., the QFT with the simplest action, that describes electron–photon interaction?**

I know that quantum electrodynamics (QED) describes this interaction. Is this also the simplest QFT that does that?

What I'm intending to do then is to (at least attempt to) go from the Heisenberg picture, which is the picture in which QFTs are usually expressed, to the Schrödinger picture, which in my opinion is more concrete (less abstract) and therefore easier to understand. I guess in the Schrödinger picture, though, it wouldn't be a QFT anymore, since the quantum fields would become independent of time and space and therefore not really fields, I suppose.

Comment: Define describe. Are limitations/regimes of validity/approximations allowed?

Comment: "go from the Heisenberg picture, which is the picture in which QFTs are usually expressed, to the Schrödinger picture, " The Shrodinger equation is non relativistic, does not have lorentz transformations, and QED  does.

Comment: @annav this doesn't make Schroedinger picture nonrelativistic. After all, you can write Dirac equation as a Schroedinger one: just choose a suitable Hamiltonian.

Comment: @Qmechanic That's a good question. What I mean by "simplest" is that if a QFT would describe a lot of other interactions as well that are not relevant to understanding how photons and electrons interact then it is too complicated. So I guess any QFT that models the interaction between those two particles very accurately but still is not too complicated would do.

Comment: @annav Using the Schrödinger picture is not the same thing as using the Schrödinger equation. You can use the Schrödinger picture but still use other equations. The  Heisenberg picture and the Schrödinger picture is just two different but equivalent ways of looking at a system, kind of like how you can represent a wave function both as a function of position and as a function of wave vector.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to work in 3+1 dimensions where electrons are fermions, QED is the simplest. You can get scalar QED by giving up the latter condition.

But if your goal is to become better acquainted with the different pictures, that can be done with $\lambda \phi^4$ or something else which isn't a gauge theory. In particular, problem 9.5 of Srednicki shows that perturbative calculations in QFT can be developed using the *interaction picture*.

One can then recover the Schroedinger or Heisenberg pictures by setting the free or interacting Hamiltonian to zero respectively. Both of these exist and even if one is more convenient, we shouldn't say it is more field theoretic than the other.